# Element-wise random choice of a Series of lists (without a loop)

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I want to randomly select an element from each list in a Series of lists.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l=[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k','l'],['m','n','o']]
s = pd.Series(l)
```

So `s` is:

```
0    [a, b, c]
1    [d, e, f]
2    [g, h, i]
3    [j, k, l]
4    [m, n, o]
dtype: object
```

I know I can do the following:

```
s = pd.Series([np.random.choice(i) for i in s])
```

Which does work:

```
0    a
1    e
2    h
3    j
4    m
dtype: object
```

But I am wondering if there is a **non-loop** approach to do this?

For instance, (assuming each `list` is equal size) you could make an array of random indices to try and pick a different element from each `list`:

```
i = np.random.randint(3, size=len(l))
#array([2, 2, 0, 1, 0])
```

But doing say `s[i]` doesn't work because that is indexing `s` rather than applying to each `list`:

```
2    [g, h, i]
2    [g, h, i]
0    [a, b, c]
1    [d, e, f]
0    [a, b, c]
dtype: object
```

My motivation is to have something that would work on a large amount of lists, hence the avoidance of a loop.  But if my list comprehension seems like the most reasonable, or there is no builtin `pandas`/`numpy` function for this, please tell me.

Comment: I think this is maybe the best way s = pd.Series([np.random.choice(i) for i in s])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only think of this way , however, the performance may be the problem

```
np.array(s.tolist())[np.arange(len(s)), np.random.randint(3, size=len(s))]
array(['c', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'n'], dtype='<U1')
```

Some timing

```
%timeit s.explode().sample(frac=1, random_state=1) 
5.05 ms ± 294 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit pd.Series([np.random.choice(i) for i in s])
23.1 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit np.array(s.tolist())[np.arange(len(s)), np.random.randint(3, size=len(s))]
1.63 ms ± 50.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `explode`, shuffle the exploded series, then sample. This doesn't even require that the lists have the same length.

```
(s.explode()
   .sample(frac=1, random_state=1)  # random_state added for repeatability, drop if needed
   .groupby(level=0).head(1)
)
```

Output:

```
1    d
2    h
0    c
3    k
4    n
dtype: object
```

Comment: Cool approach, thanks for sharing!  Also seems to also overtake the `list` comprehension with enough data on my computer